# how to use os.popen, os.path.join for command line ls in python

Tags: python, popen, os.system, os.path

I have the following directories and subdirectories with txfiles in it. I want to access them for reading the lines. But this does not work. can you help me out here?

main directory: 2009

sub directory: movies, albums, songs

each of these directory contains text files.
I want to read through each lines of these text files

my pseudocode is as folllows

```
x = os.listdir("2009")
```

Now, x will be a list of [movies, albums, songs]

```
for el in x:
  os.system("ls 2009/el")
  for lines in os.popen(2009/el"):
       print lines
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please format your code using the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want it accessing the line, (eg. printing them out as in the question), I don't think you need os.popen.

The code you have given doesn't work because it even has syntax errors.  (unmatched double quotes)

Here is some sample code which does what you're asking for.

```
>>> dirname='2009' #or the full path.
>>> for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
...     with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename)) as f:
...         for line in f.readlines():
...             print line
...
```

I hope this helps.